# Identify duplicates using 3 conditions

Tags: r, duplicates

I am new to R.  I have to write some codes to clean out potential duplicate lab records based on the following criteria.
I hope someone can give me some help on how to do this in `dplyr`?  I know there is a duplicate function in R, and also a date function in the `lubridate` package that makes it easy to define the date differences.

The clean-up rules are as follows:

1. If collection dates are **within 6 months** from the last collection date and the type is the “**same**”, then remove the record with the later collection date.
2. If collection dates are **within 6 months** from the last collection date and the type is “**different**”,  then keep both records.
3. If collection dates are **within 6 months**, and **one record has a phage type and the other one has an NA phage type**, then remove the record with the NA phage type that are within 6 months.

I would like to create a new Column called “**Flag for removal**” to mark up the records that should be removed  so we can check before removing those records.

Here is a dataset.  There are 5 clients with duplicate records, and I have included the expected results after the dataset.

```
dat0<-read.table(text="
ID  Collection_Date Type
9318    5/8/2014    SE_8
29210   2/9/2015    SE_19
31733   10/27/2014  SE_13a
31733   10/29/2014  SE_13a
35463   4/14/2015   SE_13
260717  1/7/2016    SE_8
267125  7/15/2014   SE_8
276105  12/11/2014  SE_13a
276105  1/25/2015   NA
276195  11/20/2015  SE_13a
280415  9/21/2014   SE_8
280957  4/28/2015   SE_22
281839  1/6/2016    SE_13a
281839  11/21/2016  NA
302594  8/30/2015   SE_13a
423090  1/2/2016    SE_13
434579  1/10/2015   SE_13a
438046  4/15/2015   SE_22
438046  5/19/2015   SE_8
438396  1/14/2016   SE_13a
453374  2/19/2014   SE_35
519832  1/4/2015    SE_8
520665  8/15/2014   SE_13
520665  10/9/2014   SE_13
",sep="",header=TRUE)
```

Expected Results for the 5 clients with duplicates:

```
31733   27-Oct-2014 SE_13a  Keep 
31733   29-Oct-2014 SE_13a  Delete # because  the record is within 6 months and type is the same
#-------------------
276105  11-Dec-2014 SE_13a  Keep
276105  25-Jan-2015 NA      Delete # because type is missing and record is within 6 months of the record above
#-------------------
281839  06-Jan-2016 SE_13a  Keep
281839  21-Nov-2016 NA      Keep # because dates are more than 6 months
#-------------------
438046  15-Apr-2015 SE_22   Keep
438046  19-May-2015 SE_8    Keep # because type is different even if date is within 6 months
#-------------------
520665  15-Aug-2014 SE_13   Keep
520665  09-Oct-2014 SE_13   Delete
```

Comment: Can you give some additional information? E.g.: Is it possible that an ID appears more than two times? Are the Dates always ordered ascendingly for each ID?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following (assuming that an ID can  mostly appear two times and that the dates are ordered ascendingly):

```
dat0$Collection_Date <- as.Date(dat0$Collection_Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

dat0 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate((as.numeric(as.yearmon(Collection_Date)) 
            - lag(as.numeric(as.yearmon(Collection_Date))))*12 <= 6 
           & (lag(Type) == Type) | is.na(Type))

       ID Collection_Date   Type (as.numeric(as.yearmon(Collection_Dat...
    (int)          (date) (fctr)                                    (lgl)
1    9318      2014-05-08   SE_8                                       NA
2   29210      2015-02-09  SE_19                                       NA
3   31733      2014-10-27 SE_13a                                       NA
4   31733      2014-10-29 SE_13a                                     TRUE
5   35463      2015-04-14  SE_13                                       NA
6  260717      2016-01-07   SE_8                                       NA
7  267125      2014-07-15   SE_8                                       NA
8  276105      2014-12-11 SE_13a                                       NA
9  276105      2015-01-25     NA                                     TRUE
10 276195      2015-11-20 SE_13a                                       NA
11 280415      2014-09-21   SE_8                                       NA
12 280957      2015-04-28  SE_22                                       NA
13 281839      2016-01-06 SE_13a                                       NA
14 281839      2016-11-21     NA                                     TRUE
15 302594      2015-08-30 SE_13a                                       NA
16 423090      2016-01-02  SE_13                                       NA
17 434579      2015-01-10 SE_13a                                       NA
18 438046      2015-04-15  SE_22                                       NA
19 438046      2015-05-19   SE_8                                    FALSE
20 438396      2016-01-14 SE_13a                                       NA
21 453374      2014-02-19  SE_35                                       NA
22 519832      2015-01-04   SE_8                                       NA
23 520665      2014-08-15  SE_13                                       NA
24 520665      2014-10-09  SE_13                                     TRUE
```

Where `TRUE` is indication the duplicated lines which are to be removed.

Comment: Wow, this is super useful!!!  Most results are correct with the exception of row 14 (ID 281839) where we should keep the record because the record is outside of 6 months (even though the type is NA).  So, in looking at your code, it seems correct, so I am not sure why row 14 is marked as TRUE.  Do you know why and also how to fix that?

I will also need to check the data more on Monday.  You raised a very good point because there may be more than two rows of data for each client which will make the rules even more complicated.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The value is marked as `TRUE` because it meets the 3. condition: within 6 months + one value is `NA`.